# When in camera view a grey plane appears

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera

I was playing with my POV and suddendly a grey plane, the problem is that I didn't add any, and the plane rotate with the camera, look at the photos for a better understanding.
[image]  [image]
The worst is that the plane is also rendered, I don't know what is going on.
I'm using Cycles with Supported option and my Blender version is 3.1.2.

Comment: I added a new camera, and in this one, there isn't any grey plane, but at this point my curiosity is triggered: what was missing with the previous camera?

Comment: please share your file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like your Camera's end clip plane is set too low for your scene. It cuts out the rendering of everything beyond the set distance.

Check the "Clip Start and End" section on the [camera's Blender manual page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cameras.html).